# User Details not showing from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to select data from database and show it on my website to user who is logged in but only his data not anyone else when I put the code it gives few error notices I don't know how to solve them please help me. Thanks

**Error Notice Massages:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details2.php on line 21
Username    Name
```

**Here is my php code:**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","login");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What's the schema of your `users` table?

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysqli_error());`

Comment: id,username,password,name and address

Comment: @dianuj still getting same error notices

Answer (score 0):

Try mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) or mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) instead of mysqli_fetch_array($result)